# Language is not installed on Microsoft Surface Pro

Tags: windows-8, language-pack, microsoft-surface-pro

Language is not installed on Microsoft Surface Pro. I am trying to install an additional language pack in windows 8 Surface Pro. But when I add the language and tap `option` to download a particular language it gives me `connect to internet to download.....` I am already connected to internet and browsing the Internet. What could be the problem?

Comment: do you use a firewall/proxy?